# Taking photos using the Iphone camera

Tags: iphone, photos

We have developed an iPhone app and now wish to utlise the camera to:-
- take a photograph and save it in a specific sub-directory (set up when the App is upgraded/loaded) of Photos but only when the photo is taken from within the app. All other photos should go to the standard photo folder. Is this possible and how can we do it?
- We would like to reference these photos so that pressing a link within the app history accesses that specific photo. Other photos are referenced elsewhere in the app history. Again is this possible and how can we do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction) buttonname
{
   UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)UIPicker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)info editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    [UIPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageview.image=info;
}
```